# "form" in the phrase "come well formed into"

Tags: secondary-predicates, participle-phrases

I don't understand the "**form**" in this sentence. Is the "*come well formed into*" a set phrase?

> Those (men) who come well **formed** into the world she (Nature) renders strong and robust, and destroys all the rest

Comment: I would say "come well formed" refer to something physical. Having no additional context, I would guess that it refers to those who were born without any physical defects.

Comment: The Oxford dict. states **(form people/things into)** as "organize people or things into (a group or body)". Is it suitable to interpret as "Those who are organized into the world...."? In this way, I can't explain the **well** in the sentence well.

Comment: It might be helpful to think of "well formed" as an adjective, meaning "being formed well" (which I interpreted it as "in a well shape"). In that sentence, it indicates the way those men were formed, *"Those (men) who come (in a well formed body/manner) into the world..."*.

Comment: @Damkerng T. Don't you think it should be *well-formed* then?

Comment: I read it exactly the same thing, imho, the hyphenation might be varied from one writer to another.

Comment: As far as I concerned, "Those who come well formed" divides into two parts: one is the "strong/robust" and the other is "the rest". If the whole are all well-formed, why the latter part are destroyed?

Comment: It's a comment on *survival of the fittest*.  I.e., the ones who aren't well-formed probably won't last too long.

Comment: @Jim - I believe you have answered the question nicely.

Comment: @Jim The sentence can be reworded as "she (Nature) renders { Those (men) who come well formed into the world } strong and robust, and destroys all the rest". The **render** means **make** here, right?

Comment: @wangzhihao- Yes to the reword.  Loosely for the meaning of render.  *render*: to cause to become

Comment: @DamkerngT. Ah, that changes the meaning then! *Well-formed* clarifies the sentence that men are well-formed (adjective). But isn't it *those who come well, (they) formed into the world....* means *form* as a **verb?** there I am curious to learn!

Comment: @MaulikV I'm quite reluctant to say "Those who come well, formed into the world, she renders ..." If someone really said that then it will sound to me as if the speaker might intend to say either "and was formed" or "being formed" instead.

Comment: @DamkerngT. This is interesting. You are right but do you think this stands correct? -> *Those who dressed well formed the group of queens. Others just had to sit and watch at Nancy's theme-party.* Do we require a *comma* after the word *well*?

Comment: @MaulikV No, you shouldn't use comma there. The main difference here is that "formed" is the main verb of the whole sentence. Another thing is both 'dressed' and 'formed' are in past tense because the event happened in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Come into the world* or *be brought into the world* is a common literary way of saying *be born*:

> To this end was I born, and for this cause came I into the world, that I should bear witness unto the truth. - *John 18:37 in the Christian Bible*

*Well-formed* here acts as an adjectival phrase constructed from the past participle of the verb *form*, meaning to *shape, create*, plus the adverb *well*. To ‘form’ something ‘well’ may mean either to make something competently or to give it a pleasing or suitable form—the two senses usually amount to the same thing. Here *well-formed* acts as a *subject complement* to the verb *come*; that is, it is a secondary complement modifying the subject of the verb.

So *come well formed into the world* is not, strictly speaking, a fixed phrase. However, it is interesting that the translator here has not been completely faithful to the original French text:

> La nature en use précisément avec eux comme la loi de Sparte avec les enfants des citoyens ; elle rend forts et robustes ceux qui **sont** bien constitués et fait périr tous les autres ...
>
> Nature in this case treats them exactly as Sparta treated the children of her citizens: those who **are** well formed she renders strong and robust, and all the rest she destroys ...

The translator thus adds *come into the world* to the text; and I cannot help thinking that he was influenced in this by a very famous passage from the opening monologue of Shakespeare’s *Richard III*, the wicked usurper<sup>†</sup> who was prematurely born a hunchback:

> But I, that am not shaped for sportive tricks,
> Nor made to court an amorous looking-glass;
> I, that am rudely stamped, and want love's majesty
> To strut before a wanton ambling nymph;
> I, that am curtailed of this fair proportion,
> Cheated of feature by dissembling nature,
> **Deformed**, unfinished, **sent** before my time
> **Into this breathing world** ...

---

<sup>†</sup>In the play, that is, and in Shakespeare’s source. The historical Richard appears to have been quite a different sort of man.

Answer (score -1):

The word *form* is considered here as a *verb* meaning *[create (as an entity)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/FORM)* or *to give shape*. The sentence means that those who **come well** (maybe, good persons) are the only ones accepted (and thus existed?) by her (Nature) as rest are destroyed.

The [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/form) describe **formed into** as mentioned below:

> **Bring together parts or combine to create (something)** - *the company was formed in 1982 peasants and miners were **formed into** a militia.*

Comment: I would say it's referring to those who come **strong** into this world, and that's not necessarily tied to good character. I think @Jim's comment nails it.